# how to create this design: Work Experience Tree Template

Tags: html, css

I want to make a design similar to this one:
[image]

But i am running out of ideas how to make this. Can anyone give me some hints or help me with demo.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: @Paulie_D: I tried it but didnot come close to the output that is why i didnot put the code. Will do in future quesitons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.list-component {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px
}
 /* https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001705.htm */
.list-component .__item {
  background: url(https://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/bullet.gif) no-repeat top left;
  background-position: top left;
  padding: 0 0 4px 60px;
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
  right: 67px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.card-component {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 450px;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.card-component .__year {}

.card-component .__title {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.card-component .__text {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-component">
  <li class="__item">
    <div class="card-component">
      <h2 class="__year">2010 - 2014</h2>
      <h1 class="__title">Studied at Michigan State University</h1>
      <p class="__text">Blah Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="__item">
    <div class="card-component">
      <h2 class="__year">2014 - 2016</h2>
      <h1 class="__title">Master In Computer Science</h1>
      <p class="__text">Blah Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented before - you should have come with something before asking the question.
But since it was a nice exercise. please see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/1or582su/

It is not completed. But you can take it from here.

```css
ul {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
    list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10' viewBox='-1 -1 2 2'><circle r='1' /></svg>");

}

li {
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.years, .header {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li>
  <div class="years">2001-2003</div>
  <div class="header">Studied at Cambridge</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum whatever</div>
</li>


<li>
  <div class="years">2001-2003</div>
  <div class="header">Studied at Cambridge</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum whatever</div>
</li>
</ul>
```